# Adding new column and value to empty dataframe: ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As a part of my simplified example script, I am adding a new column "generation" to my dataframe with the value "millenial". When the dataframe is empty, the first option using `df.loc` throws a ValueError, but the second approach properly creates the column as expected. Can someone please explain why the second approach successfully creates the new column on an empty dataframe, but the first approach throws a ValueError?

I also understand that I can check if a dataframe is empty prior to creating the new column, but this question stems mainly out of curiosity.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "age"], data=None)
```

This results in a "ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar"

```
df.loc[:, "generation"] = "millenial"
```

This successfully creates the "generation" column on an empty dataframe

```
df["generation"] = "millenial"
```

Comment: in the first approach, you are trying to replace values of an existing dataframe having a column "generation" which doesn't exist and hence the error is thrown. In the second approach, you are asking pandas to create a new column "generation" and then assign the value to it which is good to go.

Comment: I realized that `df = df.assign(generation="millenial")` would also work. Any reason to use one of these particular approaches? Or is one of the approaches "best practice"?

Comment: Did you tried `.at[]` ?

Comment: @Let'stry I think .at[] is primarily used for accessing a specific value (row, col index). In my case, if a dataframe is empty, the desired behavior is simply for the new column to be created, but the dataframe would still contain no rows.